# putenv warning with C++

Tags: c++, c, environment-variables

I am trying to use `putenv` `stdlib` function in a program that I am compiling with `g++` including the flags and warnings `-std=c++11` and `-Wall -Wextra`.

The program can be as easy as the following:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../Desktop/lib");
    std::cout<<"hello\n";
    return 0;

}
```

but I am getting this error `warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]`.

As far as I understood in C++ I should declare: `char const *str =` but then `putenv` is complaining.

I know I could cast but is there a proper way to use `putenv` function in C++ or being it a C function it should be completely avoided?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While [`std::getenv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) is part of the C++ standard (and the C standard as well, but in the future pick ***one*** language, the one you really program in which in your case is C++), the [`putenv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putenv.html) function isn't.

As you can see from the linked POSIX reference for [`putenv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putenv.html), it's argument is of type `char *`.

This is very important, and one thing that differs between C and C++: In C a literal string can be passed to functions expecting `char *`. In C++ all literal strings are ***constant*** and can only be passed to functions expecting `const char *`.

To solve your problem, you need to use a non-constant array that you initialize and then pass:

```
char env[] = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../Desktop/lib";
putenv(env);
```

Important note: The array must be valid during the full life-time of your program. That means even after the `main` function returns.

A better solution (and mentioned in a comment) is the [`setenv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html) function, which both takes `const char *` for its argument (and can therefore be used with literal strings) and also copies the arguments which means there's no problem about scope and life-time.

---

Regarding string literals. In both C and C++ they are really arrays of characters. The difference is that in C++ the arrays are constant.

Comment: There is no `putenv` like in C++?

Comment: there is only the old C version, there is no 'new' version accepting a `const char *` or a `std::string` etc

Comment: @FrancescoBoi The C++ standard does not specify a `putenv` function. It's an operating-system specific function.

Comment: @Osiris It's an error to let the automatic variable go out of scope. If the life-time of the array is the life-time of the program it's okay.

Comment: @bruno: [Sure there is](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude *It's an error to let the automatic variable go out of scope.*  There's no way you can safely use `putenv()` with any automatic variable.  Even an automatic variable in `main()` goes out of scope when the program returns from `main()` - but the program isn't done yet, especially in C++.  C++ destructors will run after `main()` returns, as well as any functions registered with `atexit()`.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to follow [the `putenv` manpage](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putenv.html)'s advice that you should instead use the more modern and safe [`setenv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html), which does not have this problem, nor any of the complexities that arise from it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is already pointed out by other answers. In `C++` a string literal is of type `const char[]` while in C it is `char[]`, but modifying it will lead to undefined behavior.

According to the [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html) page:

> The putenv() function adds or changes the value of environment
>          variables.  The argument string is of the form name=value.  If name
>          does not already exist in the environment, then string is added to
>          the environment.  If name does exist, then the value of name in the
>          environment is changed to value.  The string pointed to by string
>          becomes part of the environment, so altering the string changes the
>          environment.
>
> ...
>
> Thus, it is an error is to call putenv() with an
>          automatic variable as the argument, then return from the calling
>          function while string is still part of the environment.

You should be careful when you call `putenv` with a variable of automatic storage (for example if you call it in a function other than `main`) since the pointer becomes part of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

*putenv* get a (non const) `char *` and you give a `const char *`, the compiler is not happy and this normal

just do

```
char s[] = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH =../Desktop/lib";

putenv(s);
```