# C++: Iterating over a string vector and using the index for putenv

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a vector of strings which was created from parsing a config file. All the strings should be in the format `key=value`. I'd like to iterate over the vector, and use the putenv function to set an environment variable to the key-value pair.

The code:

```
for(auto it = settings.begin(); it != settings.end(); it++) {
      try {
         auto i = it - settings.begin();
         cout << i << endl;
         putenv(settings.at(i));
      } catch (...) {
         cout << "Config is not in the format key=value ... please correct" << endl;
      }
   }
```

This throws the error:

```
cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int putenv(char*)’
```

I'm very new to C++, and all these variable types and pointers are confusing me.

Comment: it is a combination of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char plus this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279450/putenv-warning-with-c

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing C and C++ stuff.

- Your vector contains C++ strings, `std::string`.
- `putenv` is an "old" function expecting a pointer to a `char` buffer, i.e. a C-string.

Fortunately, [`std::string` makes it easy to get one of those](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

```
putenv(settings.at(i).c_str());
//                   ^^^^^^^^
```

However, there is still a problem there. `putenv` takes "ownership" of the buffer you give it, and expects it to last "forever". Yours won't; it'll only be there until the `std::string` is modified or destroyed. Not good enough!

Conventionally, we use C's `strdup` here to allocate a copy of the `char` buffer. It's then `putenv`'s (or the OS's) responsibility to free it later.

```
putenv(strdup(settings.at(i).c_str()));
//     ^^^^^^^                      ^
```

Since `putenv` is not in the C or C++ standard, but is provided by POSIX, you should check the manpages for your operating system to make sure you're using it correctly.

Comment: not sure, but I found [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup): "The returned pointer must be passed to free to avoid a memory leak."

Comment: @idclev463035818 which the C library will do at a later time, after `putenv()` takes ownership of the pointer.  Although, not all implementations of `putenv()` take ownership, some make a copy of the `char` data instead, so check the documentation for your C library's particular implementation.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by your call to putenv(), which expects a pointer to  `char`'s.  Your vector contains C++ strings (std::string)...

You can try this:

```
for (auto setting : settings) {

     // ... putenv() is inconsistent across compilers, so use setenv() instead...         
     std::string key = item.substr( 0, item.find_first_of( "=" ) ) ;
     std::string val = item.substr( key.length()+1 ) ;

     if ( setenv( key.c_str(), val.c_str(), 1 ) != 0 ) {
        cerr << "setenv(" << key << ',' << val << ") has failed: " << strerror( errno ) << endl;
     }
}
```

From what I've read, `putenv` should be avoided in new code, and `setenv` should be used, as it makes a copy of its arguments, regardless of compiler version.

(`setenv` is in stdlib.h)

Comment: c-strings are `const char*` in c++ not `char*`

Comment: nope, a function expecting a `char*` will not accept a `const char*`

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279450/putenv-warning-with-c). In the question it is a warning, but thats just because of the sloppyness of `const` vs non-constness of string literals. `c_str()` definitely returns a `const char*`

Comment: btw instead of try-catch one should inspect the returned value.

Comment: Most (?) systems take ownership of the argument to `putenv`, and expect it to survive the duration of the process (unless `putenv` is called again), so this code is probably very dangerous. "Just const casting it" makes that worse.

Comment: @idclev463035818 String literals in C++ are `const char[N]` (which becomes `const char*)`, but C-strings themselves can be either really. A C-string is a null-terminated buffer; doesn't really matter whether it's mutable or not.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings It does seem that `putenv()` is hard to pin down with respect to its handling of its arguments... so I'd use `setenv()` instead

Comment: @StephanM Yep, `setenv()` is _much_ better.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings yes, sorry, my bad. I confused the usual `const char* = "hello world";` with the actualy type of the literal and thats what makes the difference to the Q&A I linked above